# How to host and access files on a Netlify site

Tags: netlify

I am using [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) to host a [github repo](https://github.com/Tehsurfer/MPB) and am trying to find a way to host additional files on the domain.

( If you don't know what Netlify is check it out. It's a fast dirty and free version of AWS code deploy as far as I understand. (Disclaimer have not used AWS code deploy))

## Example

Base Domain:

https://physiome-test.netlify.com/

Load a 3D model from

https://physiome-test.netlify.com/3Dmodels/heart/fullheart.json

Does anyone know if this is possible? I understand that they only provide 'static sites' but I don't see why that couldn't include file storage so that one doesn't have to worry about CORS

Comment: I answered your question and made suggestions to fix some of your issues. There may be other issues you will have to address with relative paths though, so this is not going to be a full fix, but should get you started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Netlify will host all static content in the folder you tell it to on deploy. You are currently telling Netlify to put your whole repository into the site starting at the root of the repository. This is causing issues with your relative paths.

You can go to any path in your repository at this time on your site and get a returned response of the file.

## Solution:

Build your site into one build location and have Netlify deploy that location to the site. Any path relative to the root path of the location will be the root of your site.

**1.** Put the `body` assets under your `simple_heart/models` directory at `simple_heart/models/body`

**2.** `netlify.toml` (root of your repository)

```
[build]
  command = "cp -r ./simple_heart ./build && npm run build"
  publish = "build"
```

**3.** Fix your index.html in the `simple_heart` to reflect the relative paths from the root of `simple_heart` which will now be the root of your site with the build assets `physiomeportal.js` and `physiomeportal.min.js` at the root of your site.

**note:** To see this, run the command from the root of your site on a local build.

Comment: Wow amazing answer! Thank you for even making it specific to my project. I did not know that Netlify will host the whole repo so never thought to try accessing https://physiome-test.netlify.com/simple_heart/index.html which is able to load the model!

Comment: Yeah, it makes it easy to test out the whole process locally and decide how you want to build out your static content to be deployed. 